# Trouble with Print Dialog Focus In Java

Tags: java, swing, printing, jframe, print-job-control

I have a JFrame and it opens java Print Dialog.Like below

```
 PrinterJob pj = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
  if (pj.printDialog()) {
      //Print
    }
```

The problem is that my JFrame has  the **setAlwaysOnTop(true)** attribute and Print dialog is opened in the background of the JFrame. To solve this problem I want to follow such a way

Before opening Printdialog, i will set  setAlwaysOnTop(false) After opening print dialog  i will set setAlwaysOnTop(true) again.

But how to know my print dilaog is opened ?

Because pj.printDialog() is waiting.

How to get the print dilaog opened event ?

Comment: Have you tried just putting it before and after that block of code?  It might work fine to just wait until after it prints to revert the setting

Answer (score 0):

You can use printrequestAttributeSet object to brint printer dialog on top. For example;

```
PrintRequestAttributeSet set = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
set.add(OrientationRequested.LANDSCAPE);
set.add(new sun.print.DialogOnTop());
```

Then , use

```
pj.printDialog(set)
```